# how to cap server bandwidth to each client in a network?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a pc with windows server 2008 r2 and 100 mbps network bandwidth

when a another PC connect to server pc and start copying files from server i want the server to cap bandwidth to this pc to 2 mbps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows QoS is not that powerful as a router and thus using router with more control over traffic is better some thing like pfsense

pfsense uses ipfw firewall and named as limiter in pfsense

can setup windows server and pfsense on the same machine as VMs and let pfsense control windows server bandwidth

and the setup that i want is dynamic limiter on bridge in pfsense configuration

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Policy-based QoS within the local computer policy (gpedit.msc) on your server. Create a Policy with an outbound throttle rate of 2Mbps, apply to All Applications, any source IP (or the server's own IP if you prefer), destination IP of the PC concerned, source port 445 (which is SMB file sharing).

See also https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759093.aspx for more information

Comment: my server IP is not static and concerned PC is not static

Comment: It would be a lot easier if they were. Otherwise you could relatively easily make it a policy that affects all clients if you were happy to throttle everyone to 2Mbps each? Or you could try an inbound policy on the client PC itself although I'm not sure how effective that would be.

Comment: i have no control over clients so all what i do can be done from the server side